# Custom WPF DataGrid Scrollbar With LineUp / LineDown Repeat Buttons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to make a custom WPF DataGrid ScrollBar to look like the following:

[image]

But till that moment, I can only do the ScrollBar without triangle buttons:

[image]

Here is the XAML code for what I have now:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Fill="Transparent" />
                        <Border x:Name="Rectangle1" CornerRadius="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Background="{StaticResource GreenBackColor}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                            <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Height" Value="7" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#8C8C8C" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayBackColor}" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="8" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="8" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="true" Focusable="false">
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                            </Track.Thumb>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Value="{DynamicResource ButtonSelectBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                            <Setter Value="{DynamicResource DarkBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                            <Setter TargetName="GridRoot" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="8" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PageDown" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PageUp" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Polygon Points="0,0 0,6, 0,10" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

How can I add those triangles as a RepeatButtons?

Comment: Please at least leave a comment on downvoting

Comment: @glautrou nope, tried to draw a triangle polygon on RpeatButton, but that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to do this myself and found your post while searching. You need to add RepeatButtons for ScrollBar.LineUpCommand and LineDownCommand buttons (above and below the track) to your ScrollBar ControlTemplate as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Height="18" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}" />
    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" IsDirectionReversed="true" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}" Style="..."/>
        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" Style="..."/>
        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        <Track.Thumb>
            <Thumb Style="..." Width="14"/>
        </Track.Thumb>
    </Track>
    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2" Height="18" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

Sacha has a full sample here [link](https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/styling-a-scrollviewerscrollbar-in-wpf/).